# How to fix just one rule using eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I want to use eslint command flag `--fix` to just fix one rule. And I tried the command: `eslint --fix --config ./.eslintrcsomerules.js .`. But it does not work. How to achieve the object?

My **.eslintrcsomerules.js** file is below:

```
module.exports = {
  'rules': {
    'indent': [2, 2],
  }
};
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/4.0.0/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 24):

To fix the issues caused by **just one** rule, you need to combine `--fix --rule` with `--no-eslintrc`. Otherwise your rule will just be merged with your existing configuration and all fixable issues will be corrected. E.g.

```sh
$ eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'indent: [2, 2]'
```

Depending on your setup you'll need to re-add mandatory settings from your ESLint configuration to the command line for the lint run to succeed. In my case I had to use

```sh
$ eslint --no-eslintrc --parser babel-eslint --fix --rule 'indent: [2, 2]'
```

Comment: More mandatory settings you might need to add can be found here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface

Comment: In my case, it was `eslint --no-eslintrc --parser babel-eslint --plugin react --parser-options ecmaVersion:12 --parser-options sourceType:module --parser-options ecmaFeatures:{jsx:true} --fix --rule 'indent: [2, 2]'`

Answer (score 19):

I struggled with this. I was using create-react-app and it was very difficult to turn off all the rules but keep all the configs to parse ES6/TS/etc.

This library was exactly what I wanted! I can see how many errors there are for each rule *and selectively fix one rule at a time*
https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble

Comment: I'm the author of eslint-nibble, I'm glad you find it useful!  Under the hood, it uses https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-filtered-fix, which can also be used directly if you're just looking for a simple CLI tool.

Answer (score 16):

You can pass a `--rule` flag with the rule you want to fix. For example:

```
eslint --fix --rule 'quotes: [2, double]' .
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#rule) for more information.

The [list of available rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) might also be helpful.

Comment: Another example: 
`yarn lint --fix --rule '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style: error'`

Comment: `npm run lint --fix --rule '"arrow-parens": ["warn", "as-needed"]` is not working , any idea, @Lucas Caton

Comment: link to CLI rule arg: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#--rule

Answer (score 1):

The answers suggesting ignoring .eslintrc with

```bash
eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'indent: [2, 2]'
```

may fail if your .eslintrc contains preprocessors without which you get errors, such as

```
Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved
```

I recommend using [eslint-interactive](https://github.com/mizdra/eslint-interactive), which will let you select the rules you want to fix:

```bash
yarn install -D eslint-interactive
eslint-interactive . # This will interactively guide you.
yarn remove -D eslint-interactive
```