# Eslint CLI No files matching the pattern "['warn']'" were found

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm trying to lint certain rules via the eslint CLI in my create-react-app. The rule I'd like to fix is `react/jsx-sort-props`.

At first I tried the format for fixing single rules provided here: [How to fix just one rule using eslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828664/how-to-fix-just-one-rule-using-eslint)

```
"fix-style":"eslint --fix --rule 'react/jsx-sort-props"
```

But this gives error:

```
Invalid value for option 'rule' - expected type Object, received value: 'react/jsx-sort-props.
```

This error is discussed in [ESLint CLI with --rule option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050338/eslint-cli-with-rule-option) but none of the solutions seem to work.

Running:

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "fix-style": "eslint --fix --rule 'react/jsx-sort-props: ['warn']'",
}
```

Gives:

```
$ eslint --fix --rule 'react/jsx-sort-props: ['warn']'

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.32.0

No files matching the pattern "['warn']'" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

So what's the correct way to fix a single rule?

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner single-quotes ended the rule string prematurely, so use double quotes to surround the entire string

try: `eslint --fix --rule "react/jsx-sort-props: ['warn']"`

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to escape the double quotes when using the command in my `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "fix-style": "eslint --fix --rule \"react/jsx-sort-props: ['warn']\"",
  },
```